# Python: performing a function to check if the file has a suffix

Tags: python, performance, error-handling, coding-style

I wrote this function to use from an other function, checking if the output has the correct suffix. Before I use it I have two questions:

1. Is `TypeError` the best [exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) to use in this case?
2. Is there some built-in function I could use instead of mine?

Code:

```
def suffix_NameCheck(inFile):
    if os.path.splitext(inFile)[1] is None:
        raise TypeError('"%s" has not a suffix' % inFile)
    else:
        return inFile
```

Comment: I would expect from a function named `xxx_check` to return a boolean instead of throwing an exception. However, `ValueError` is a better fit for this case, I think.

Comment: I prefer my thing-checking functions to return booleans. something like `def hasSuffix(inFile): return os.path.splitext(inFile)[1] is not None`.

Comment: Suppose you find out that the file **name** (not the file itself! that doesn't make any sense) has a suffix (or not); *now what*? Why does the rest of the code care?

Comment: Note that your condition is incorrect.  The docs on `splitext()` say the second value in the 2-tuple will be an empty string in the case no extension was found, not `None`, so your condition here will always evaluate `False`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I wondering that - might as well just have `'.' in inFile`

Comment: @JonClements Not quite; `splittext()` ignores leading periods on file names.  If you want a better equivalency, it would be `'.' in itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: c == '.', os.path.split(candidate)[1])`.

Comment: @Kevin: maybe i wrong, but your function returns always True

Comment: @Gianni, perhaps, but I based it on your `suffix_NameCheck` method. So if mine always returns True, yours never raises an exception.

Comment: @Kevin You are both right; see my comment (#4).

Answer (score 7):

There is not a built-in function that does this, because

1. Not all file systems really use extensions.
2. It's probably more common to just use the if statement on its own, rather than throwing it in a function.

The reason is that you're probably going to have to catch that exception somewhere (unless you intentionally want it to end the program, in which case, there's probably a better way to do it than throwing an exception, e.g. `sys.exit`). The code to catch the exception would be at least as involved as the code to just do the `if` check itself and handle it.

Comment: Not convinced I like library functions exiting for me. At the very least, instead of `sys.exit` I would rather it threw a `SystemExit` and I can do something "a bit more controlled" higher-up should I need to.

Comment: @JonClements it wasn't specified whether this was a library or part of an individual program. (Furthermore, the point was that this doesn't necessarily belong in a function in the first place.)

Comment: @Amber , thanks for help and tips. By the way is i use ex sample.jpg or sample (without suffix) the function return always inFile because os.path.splitext(inFile)[1] is ""

Comment: @Gianni so change `is None` to `== ""` - not sure why you're insisting on checking for `None` if the behavior of the function is to return `""`.

Answer (score 5):

I would not raise an exception from a function named `suffix_NameCheck`, but rather return `True` or `False` instead. The normal operation of `suffix_NameCheck` is not affected by wether or not there is a correct suffix on the value, it's *job* is to check for that suffix.

The function that *uses* `suffix_NameCheck` could still raise an exception; `ValueError` may be a better exception to use in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more appropriately a `ValueError`.  The problem you are attempting to report is that the user provided a file path/name argument as a string that has no file extension.  That's a problem with the value of the string, not anything's type.

Other answerers have a point that this sort of functionality at first glance should really be returning a `bool`, but given that that use case is covered simply with `bool(os.path.splitext(candidate)[1])`, I think that if you really do want to raise an exception here, you are already working with a lower level function that returns a `bool`.